# При преобразовании String в Double выдаёт ошибку

Tags: java

```
public class Variables {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String str_s = "53,5";
        Double b = Double.parseDouble(str_s);

        System.out.println("b");

    }

}
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input
>   string: "53,5"    at
>   sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
>     at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)   at
>   java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)     at
>   variables.Variables.main(Variables.java:20)
>   C:\Users\Gidravlic\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Variables\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1040:
>   The following error occurred while executing this line:
>   C:\Users\Gidravlic\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Variables\nbproject\build-impl.xml:805:
>   Java returned: 1 СБОРКА ЗАВЕРШЕНА СО СБОЕМ (общее время: 0 секунд)

Comment: `String str_s = "53.5";`

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!

Comment: на машине с другой локалью получите уже ошибку с "53.5" :-)

Comment: Не подскажите почему, или где об этом прочесть подробнее? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Способ использования запятой вместо точки указан [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4323628/5122436)

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас изучим.